# on scroll to each paragraph increase the size and after when scroll is not in the paragraph decrease the size with jquery

Tags: javascript

i just want to increase the font size of each paragraph when scroll is near to them and decrease after when scroll is down.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('.title').css('font-size', '43px');
        } else {
            $('.title').css('font-size', '36px');
        }
    });
    
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`element.getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) can help you in this case. Iterate through every `.title`, then resize accordingly.

### Update

You can have a look at [CSS transition](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition.asp) property to adjust font resize speed.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        $('.title').each(function(){
          if (this.getBoundingClientRect().top < 100) {
              $(this).css('font-size', '43px');
          } else {
              $(this).css('font-size', '36px');
          }
        });
    });
    $(window).scroll();
});
```

```css
body{
  height: 1000px;
}

.title {
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  transition: font-size 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="title">Hello world</div>
<div class="title">Hello world</div>
<div class="title">Hello world</div>
<div class="title">Hello world</div>
<div class="title">Hello world</div>
```

Comment: Thum Choon Tat Thank you very much, and can you help me to get some animate effect on  it? it changes too fast

Comment: @Marie updated my answer, also look for CSS transition property

Comment: Choon Thank you)